# @font-face issues

Tags: css, font-face, embedded-fonts

I have done this before, but still haven't mastered it. I downloaded a font kit from fontsquirrel.com and tried to get my custom font to work on my site. I have tried so many variations including the "bullet proof" methods found online that I have now confused myself. Could someone look at the code below and show me how to correctly get a custom font to work on a website using @font-face?

I have a style sheet named **fonts.css** located in a folder named **css**. This is being used to call the custom font. The font files are located in a folder from the root named **fonts**.

The css for the style sheet **fonts** is:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular';
    src: url('../fonts/bebasneue-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../fonts/bebasneue-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('../fonts/bebasneue-webfont.webfontABYyK1dn') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
```

The other styles sheets for layout, etc call the font like this:

```
}
#merchandise h1 {
    font-family: "Bebas Neue", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 33px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

Anything obvious? Of course, it works locally on my machine because I have the font installed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In `#merchandise h1`, `font-family: "Bebas Neue"` needs to be `font-family: "BebasNeueRegular"`

**or**

In `@font-face`, `font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular'` needs to be  `font-family: 'Bebas Neue'`

Comment: Thanks Josh. Stupid. The font is named BebasNeueRegular, so it must have been something else I was referencing as I wrongly used Bebas Neue when trying to call the font. Also, I was supposed to use a single quote as in 'BebasNeueRegular' instead of "BebasNeueRegular". Thanks for pointing it out to me :) Too many projects, not enough sleep!